# How to highlight the selected bootstrap tab in React

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using react for my application, and I have a bootstrap navigation bar menu has three tabs. I want to highlight the selected tab.

Here is the html code in my render() function.

```
<div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
  <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
    <li onClick={event => this.handleClick('tab1', event)} className={(this.state.activeTabClassName === "tab1") ? "active" : ""}><a href="#">HOME<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
    <li onClick={event => this.handleClick('tab2', event)} className={(this.state.activeTabClassName === "tab2") ? "active" : ""}><a href="/#/resources">RESOURCES</a></li>
    <li onClick={event => this.handleClick('tab3', event)} className={(this.state.activeTabClassName === "tab3") ? "active" : ""}><a href="/#/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I use the handleClick function to change the tabName:

```
   handleClick(tabName, event) {
    this.setState ({activeTabClassName : tabName});
    //this.state.activeTabClassName = tabName;
  }
```

I also set the initial state of activeTabClassName as 'tab1' in my constructor:

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {activeTabClassName : "tab1"}; 
   // this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }
```

The code for the whole Nav.js component

```
import React from 'react';
export default class Nav extends React.Component {

  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {activeTabClassName : "tab1"}; 
  }

  handleClick(tabName, event) {
    this.setState ({activeTabClassName : tabName});
  }

  render(){
    return(
<nav className="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div className="container-fluid">
    <div className="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" className="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span className="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
        <span className="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a className="navbar-brand navbar-utimg" href="https://www.xxx.xxxx" target="_blank">
          <img alt="logo" src="/dist/assets/coe-logo.png"/>
      </a>
    </div>

    <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul className="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li onClick={event => this.handleClick('tab1', event)} className={(this.state.activeTabClassName === "tab1") ? "active" : ""}><a href="#">HOME<span className="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li onClick={event => this.handleClick('tab2', event)} className={(this.state.activeTabClassName === "tab2") ? "active" : ""}><a href="/#/resources">RESOURCES</a></li>
        <li onClick={event => this.handleClick('tab3', event)} className={(this.state.activeTabClassName === "tab3") ? "active" : ""}><a href="/#/contact">CONTACT</a></li>
      </ul>
      <form className="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
        <div className="form-group">
          <input type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Search"/>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    </div>
</nav>
    )
  }
```

}

However, it does not work well. Everytime when click the tab, it does not highlight the selected tab unless I clicked it again. Why does the onClick function not change the state right away? Is there any better solution for this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: The code looks ok. I think the problem lies somewhere else, could you share the whole code of the component?

Comment: This is just a navigation bar component, it is relatively simple. I updated the question with the component code. Thanks!

Comment: Ok I've pulled bootstrap 3.3.6 along with jquery 2.2.4 and everything worked with single click. I was thinking that you possibly overwrote shouldComponentUpdate and it prevented the component from being rerendered but you weren't. Unless the parent that includes Nav does that and it [short circuits the update](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/advanced-performance.html), I don't know what causes the problem

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think I know what the problem is now. I called this <Nav /> component every time when the user change a route. For example, I would call <Nav /> in Home, then would call it in RESOURCES page too. Therefore, it set activeTabClassName as 'tab1' every time. So I guess I just need to call Nav in the App.js rather than in each component. Thanks again!